# Visual Studio debug ghost cursor - program enters debug but cannot see current line nor variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008

Strange situation when I am debuging a C++ application in Visual Studio.

I have set a breakpoint in my file and started debug, and run the scenario.
The application enters debug mode in visual studio at the set breakpoint, but:

- I do not see the current line/cursor
- there is no call stack displayed
- there are no variables in Autos
- in my Breakpoints list I see my breakpoint highlighted/bold (which means the debug is on the correct line)

Anyone ?
hope I have been somewhat clear...

Comment: I have tried the Run to cursor a few lines below, the functionality works (application advances) but I still do not see the cursor/current debug line, and more important I do not see variables values

Comment: For all the other files in my project debug is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Visual Studio command "Debug.ShowNextStatement" (default Alt+Num*)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the file you've loaded into the debugger isn't exactly the same version that was compiled.

Comment: it is the correct file, I checked and built and rebuilt many times ... if the file is not the same, the breakpoint is invalidated